# CakePHP internationalization

Tags: php, cakephp, encoding, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

How to handle internationalization in cakephp 3 when doing unit testing ? 
In my case I need to do `assertResponseContains('Tilføj')` which contains 'ø' character and for some reason phpunit cant read it properly, therefore the test fails even though the response contains the given word. Any suggestions ? .

Comment: Are you sure your files are all encoded properly, using UTF8? Then it should match just fine afaik.

Comment: Yes its all set properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. I was actually running the test from a command line that was not able to display correctly the "Ø" letter. So the solution was actually to change the code page of the terminal to UTF-8 with `chcp 65001 i`command